# Incredibly SLOW installation - ASUS P5Q SE PLUS & Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, intel-pentium

The last time I installed Windows 7 was the 32-bit version on my 2005 ABIT AS8 board with a Pentium 4 670 3.8GHz CPU.  This took around 30mins and worked fine but for some unknown reason, my current 2008 **ASUS P5Q SE PLUS** board with the same old CPU, took over TEN HOURS to reach approx 67%! It took an hour to reach just 9%.  I cancelled the install and decided to remove a stick of RAM to leave one 2GB stick, but that made no difference and possibly made it even slower.  Perhaps there are BIOS settings that require changing from their default AUTO settings.

The ASUS board has Kingston HyperX DDR2 1066MHz (**KHX8500D2K2/4G**) RAM in a dual channel configuration.  This is running at 800MHz FSB due to the CPU and also I believe a default safe setting by the RAM itself.  The PSU is a new 550W OCZ Fatality model and the graphics card is a ASUS GeForce GTX550 Ti DirectCU, which has an additional 6-pin PSU socket.  For the CPU I applied fresh new thermal compound paste, as I noticed the temps were in the high 80°C.  The system as a whole is running very cool.

The motherboard only has one IDE port and I do not own any SATA hard disk / DVD drives, so I connected the DVD writer to a USB 2.0 port.  The hard drive used for the Win 7 install is on the IDE port.  A floppy drive is connected.

I suppose I could also try installing other operating systems as a test, but I mainly want to use Windows XP Pro and 7 Enterprise 64-bit via a drive caddy.

Any thoughts or help appreciated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

*** SOLVED ***

Okay I managed to work it out.  The problem was the IcyDock IDE drive caddy, and once I had removed the IDE drive from this and connected it directly to the motherboard IDE port, every single problem disappeared.  So I have no installed my graphics drivers etc and had no issues since.